# Proving that $|a-b|≤|a|+|b|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Can someone prove this to me:
$$|a-b|≤|a|+|b|$$
 I am in 8th grade and I have this for my homework.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Ideally we'll help you figure it out, but not outright do the problem for you. What have you tried so far? What do you know about absolute value?

Comment: A related inequality, possibly one you studied in class, is the triangle inequality:  $$ |a+b| \le |a| + |b| $$  If you know this, the one you ask about is easily derived.

Comment: |x| is always positive. |x|<2  =>  -2 < x < 2.  -5=|5|=5

Answer (score 2):

HINT: There are much slicker, shorter arguments, but the most straightforward approach is to divide it into cases:

- $a\le b\le 0$;
- $a\le 0\le b$;
- $0\le a\le b$;
- $b\le a\le 0$;
- $b\le 0\le a$; and
- $0\le b\le a$.

Check that these cover all possibilities, and note that in each case you can get rid of the absolute values.

Answer (score 1):

Square both members: you can because the numbers involved are non negative. You get the equivalent inequality
$$
a^2-2ab+b^2\le a^2+2|ab|+b^2
$$
(justify the passages), that reduces to the equivalent inequality
$$
-ab\le |ab|
$$

Is this inequality true?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $a-b=a+(-b)$. I suppose you know the *triangle inequality*.

If you have to prove it from scratch, another hint:

$\lvert x\rvert \le\lvert y\rvert \iff\lvert x\rvert^2 \le\lvert y\rvert^2\iff x^2\le y^2$.